# Script to remove all certificates expired Windows 10

Tags: certificate

How could I script in windows 10 to remove all expired certificates at once?

I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

How about PowerShell?

```
$now = [DateTime]::Now;
$certPath = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My";
foreach($cert in Get-ChildItem -Path $certPath){
  if($cert.NotAfter -lt $now){
    Write-Host "Found a certificate:" -ForegroundColor Cyan;
    Write-Host $cert.Subject
    Write-Host "Do you want to delete it? [Y/N]" -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline;
    $confirm = Read-Host;
    if($confirm -eq "Y"){
      Remove-Item "$($certPath)\$($cert.Thumbprint)" -Force;
    }
  } 
}
```